# how to find a Explorer Window with Name Path X is exist?

Tags: c#

how to find a Explorer Window with Name Path 'X' is exist ?

for example there is a window that show "C:\" .

Comment: Do you mean the address bar or the window title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be very difficult to do.  You can try using the Win32 API to enumerate all windows and their child windows to see if you can find that text in, say, the location bar (see [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183009)), but maybe there's an easier approach to the problem you're addressing.  If, for example, you want to open an Explorer window to "C:\", you can pass "C:\" as the command to `StartProcess`.  At least from my XP box, that will not open a duplicate Explorer window if one's already opened to "C:\".

Comment: Could you share your full "command line" that re-uses duplicate windows?